# Ionic - capture Image for specific ion-row

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, html2canvas

I am developing an application in Ionic 3. I have to develop an overlay for hair simulation. The overlay has been done. Want to save that overlay section as an image for final review and future perspective. Here is my code. I want to create a snapshot for specific `div(gallery-box)`.

```
    <ion-grid padding>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>

        <div class="gallery-box">
          <img [src]="picToView" alt="" style="border-radius:50%;width:50%" />
          <img src="/path/to/Image.png" class="FinalOverlay" *ngFor="let itm of DynamicOverlay" style="width: 22%;position: absolute;left: 39%;" >
        </div>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-row  *ngFor="let item of Choice">
    <ion-col class="button" padding *ngIf="item[1] !=0">

      <div>
        <ion-label style="font-size:larger">Densidad para el Área </ion-label>
      </div>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: you may add way more specific info, like how is the provided sample works already, what is the problem between the current state and the desired one, etc.

Comment: i want something like html2canvas feature for ionic.

Comment: hi, do you got any solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to html2canvas npm package.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas